# I'm trying to make a function "InOrder", which does inorder traversing in Binary Search

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-search-tree, inorder

I'm trying to make InOrder in void-type, which executes in-order traversal in a binary search tree.

```
//Code Provided by Professor
//Program 5.1:Inorder traversal of a binary tree
//===============================================
  template <class T>
  void Tree<T>::Inorder()
  {// Driver.
     Inorder(root);
  }

 template <class T>
 void Tree<T>::Inorder(TreeNode<T> *currentNode)
  {// Workhorse.
 if (currentNode) {
     Inorder(currentNode->leftChild); 
     Visit(currentNode);
     Inorder(currentNode->rightChild);
     }
   }
```

The above code is provided by Professor, as a reference making my own InOrder function.

This Code is how I declared the elements(requisites) for my binary search tree.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template<class K, class E>
class BinarySearchTree 
{
public:
    virtual void Insert(const pair<K, E>&) = 0;
    virtual void Delete(const K&) = 0;
    virtual pair<K, E>*Get(const K&) const = 0;
    virtual void InOrder()const;
};
template<class T>
struct TreeNode {
    T data;
    TreeNode<T> *leftChild;
    TreeNode<T> *rightChild;
    TreeNode(T node) : data(node), leftChild(0), rightChild(0) {}
};

template<class K, class E>
class BST : BinarySearchTree<K, E> {
public:
    BST() : root(0) {}
    void Insert(const pair<K, E>&);
    void Delete(const K&);
    pair<K, E>*Get(const K&)const;
    void InOrder()const;

private:
    TreeNode<pair<K, E>> *root;
};
```

Other functions work well, and I would appreciate any help with making InOrder function, using C++.

Comment: You were given the code with just slightly different types, so please explain what you're having problems with.

Comment: @RR could you explain why insert takes a pair? What are K, E implies to? TreeNode stores only one type(class).

Comment: Perhaps you're expected to discover that inorder traversal of a binary *search* tree is exactly the same as inorder traversal of an arbitrary kind of binary tree.

Comment: Unrelated, but your classes contain a bunch of raw pointers. That means they should have non trivial destructors, and explicit or deleted copy/move ctor and assignment operators.

Comment: @Lakhera Insert takes a pair because TreeNode pair is made in form of <key,element>. Thats why.

Comment: @molbdnilo I cant understad what “visit” exactly does in that code that professor gave.

Comment: @R.R It doesn't do anything; you should replace it with what you want to do. For instance, you can print the key and element.

Comment: @molbdnilo I kinda heard that visit function shows if the in-order traversal has visited that specific node by 0 or 1.(true false)

Comment: @R.R I suspect that you heard something like that in a different context. An inorder traversal of an entire binary tree visits every node exactly once. If you traverse only part of a tree, you may want to know which nodes you've visited, but that's not what you're going to do in this exercise.

Comment: @molbdnilo exactly!! I know inorder traversal visits every node just one time. If I am to make visit function as a function that displays node on cout, where should I declare InOrder and Visit function in my code? And which type? I always struggle to find the right place to declare a function and its type :(

Answer (score 0):

The concept of *in order* is just the concept of order. You must also say what should be done in that order. The code provided by your professor calls a `visit` function.

That means that in your implementation, you also need such a visit function. It can either be hardcoded (display a node on `cout`) or better passed as a parameter. In that case, you should declare `InOrder` as:

```
void InOrder(void (*visit)(const pair<K, E>&))const;
```

And later call it (for example with a lambda function) as:

```
BST<int, string> bst;
...
bst.InOrder([](const pair<int, string>&ke) {
    cout << "K: " << ke.first << " -E: " << ke.second << "\n";
});
```

A possible implementation mimicing your professor's code could be:

```
template<class K, class E>
void BST<K,E>::doInOrder(const TN* root, void (*visit)(const pair<K, E>&)) {
    if (root) {
        doInOrder(root->leftChild, visit);
        visit(root->data);
        doInOrder(root->rightChild, visit);
    }
}

template<class K, class E>
void BST<K,E>::InOrder(void (*visit)(const pair<K, E>&))const {
    doInOrder(root, visit);
}
```